# TS loop properties from Partial<Class> and set it to Class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a basic JS class. A very heavily simplified example would be

```
class Test {
  a: number = 1;
  b: string = 'foo';

  populate(data){
    for (let i in data) {
      this[i] = data[i];
    }
  }
}
```

So I can basically populate an instance based on JSON data from an API.

```
const myClass = new Test();
myClass.populate({
  a: 3, 
  b: 'hello world'
});
```

This all works and is used in production for several years (of course with included `hasOwProperty` and `typeof !== 'undefined'` checks and so on).

I would like to properly code this in TypeScript, but I have no idea how, because everything fails. I had so many attempts with no avail, for example:

```
class Test {
    a: number = 1;
    b: string = 'B';

    populate(data: Partial<Test>){
        for(let i in data){
            const v = data[i as keyof Partial<Test>];
            if(v && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, i)){
                this[i as keyof Test] = v; // error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
            }
        }
    }
}

const a = new Test();
a.populate({
    a: 2,
    b: 'bar'
});
```

What could I do except a `//@ts-ignore` and `[key: string]: any` (I would like to omit `any`s) to make this working?
[Here is my playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?keyofStringsOnly=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoaXpgFzQDsBXAWwCN4AnaAXmgEYBuTbM-ZSgSwIHNboA5ACEBzFlgAOAewlFwSeAAoAJmCR5oABTCUknMCAA8CZAD4AlBmzXoAMymVFIeCk7Ru0Vesvib14FIEyNAAbvxeYADabpDQANbwAJ5Stlo6egbGiEimALrMfn6ctophAGRl0ADyZABW8MBIAHQSlFJI7YkS8E0AFpBVAO4Emm3duolNwAYgiki9nBAANO7mPoUb0POL0TgwCcmpJki5-CEFm1gAvr7WN3foN%20gBQShg-ATwg3DZiubMYBaMjkaiUVmwGgATEtfGxBGQdAJHv8gA)

Comment: try `(this as any)[i]=v` instead of `this[i as keyof Test] = v;`.
Btw (this)[https://tsplay.dev/Wo8V9w] example shows that you should maybe check for the populate key for not loosing your original reference

Answer (score 2):

How about this :)

```
class Test {
    populate(data: Partial<Test>) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In the case you described, you can try:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    if(this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        Object.assign(this, { [key]: value });
    }
}
```

The better solution might be to look into validation libraries, such as [zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod), so that you can catch that sort of error earlier in your code, before it reaches the `populate` function.

Comment: This does not work unfortunatelly as `Object.assign` has other side effects. I need a `for in` loop in order to check if my class actually has these attributes for security reasons. As said it's more about the TS part how to properly type it and not about the JS part

Comment: Thank you very much, this would indeed work, but it takes much longer than just a regular `this[i] = data[i]` I've checked it and since most of my objects are really large it took me 0.7s to populate a large amount compared to 0.2s. It would matter in production to use object assign just for TS. I would rather use a `ts-ignore` then. I guess there is no TS-only solution for this